# Performing VCS Refresh... (Takes too long or never finishes)

Tags: git, intellij-idea, svn, phpstorm

What is the fix for the issue when trying to commit from IntelliJ:

[image]

This windows either takes too long or does not finished at all. What is the work around so I can commit again from IntelliJ

Comment: I am new to IntelliJ , and using Intellij IDEA 15.0.6. I am also facing the same issue. Code commit  is a basic activity, but this bug is exists for ~4 years :-(

Comment: Such a basic issue. Still hurting me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> What is the work around so I can commit again from IntelliJ

On IntelliJ, not sure: older similar bugs have been closed (as "obsolete"), like [IDEA-63491](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-63491#tab=History)

A more recent one ([IDEA-93086](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-93086)) states:

> It works again after a fresh checkout.

As a workaround, the solution would be to push from the command-line (so outside IntelliJ).

Comment: Thanks, it means IntelliJ can't handle it.

Comment: Intellij really sucks at SVN, it doesn't even shows the log of files it is committing

Answer (score 98):

In IntelliJ navigate to:

> File > Invalidate Caches / Restart...

and select the highlighted:

> Invalidate and Restart

Comment: If still not working, try VCS > Refresh File Status from the root directory or your project. Useful if you've run git from the command line.

Comment: Beware this will close all open projects, not only the one you want to invalidate the cache.

Answer (score 12):

Just ran into this issue on WebStorm 2016.1 on Windows 8.1. 
What fixed it for me is **deleting the vcs-log directory**.
I also have IntelliJ Community Edition installed which didn't have this problem at the time so I figured it must be an issue with the application settings (hidden directory in home folder) not the project specific settings (.idea folder in the project directory).

Close IntelliJ/Webstorm and go to your home folder, you'll find a hidden directory there where IntelliJ/Webstorm keeps it's configuration. 
(The name of this hidden directory depends on the application name (IntelliJ/PHPStorm/Webstorm) and it's version:

```
C:\Users\{ your user name of pc }\.WebStorm2016.1
```

Inside there is a system folder which in turn has a vcs-log folder.

```
C:\Users\{ your user name of pc }\.WebStorm2016.1\system\vcs-log
```

Delete or rename the **vcs-log** folder and restart the application and everything should return to normal.

Comment: For PHPstorm deleting the folders out of vcs-cache fixed my issue

Comment: This worked for me when the Invalidate Caches/Restart and VCS/Refresh File Status didn't resolve the issue (both have in the past)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with PyCharm and none of the above solutions helped me.

What worked for me was the following:

1. Rename project's folder
2. Removed .idea folder
3. Rename the project's folder to previous name
4. Open it with PyCharm and the annoying "Performing VCS Refresh" was gone.

Comment: Thank you ! this worked for me. Also, FWIW, I was at the same time trying to develop a Dash/Plotly app which was loading glacially slowly ... and that has also enormously improved load time now.

Answer (score 3):

Invalidate Caches and Restart, and a fresh checkout did not work for me.

Opening the project in IntelliJ after **deleting the .idea folder** helped.

Comment: Same here! Worth mentioning that in my case, the IDEA-level project root had somehow been marked as `<project dir>/.idea` (so all configuration paths etc were being displayed like `../.git`, `../src` ...) - so the IDEA config was effectively corrupted, which could have caused the VCS refresh issues in the first place

Answer (score 2):

A fresh checkout did nothing for me.

However, this helped: "I have two projects open. One is using SVN and the other is not. When I close the one that is not using SVN. The system is responsive and I can checkin once again." [Source](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206197409--Performing-VCS-Refresh-hang)

So I removed all of my projects from the workspace, including the hidden folder .idea, and thus created a fresh workspace. Then I checked out one project via SVN, and **ever since I can commit again**.

Answer (score 2):

If you are complaining that it is slow when you commit, you can follow the steps below.

Go to git commit screen with command + K

Right Click **Unversioned File**

Disable **Show Unversioned Files**

[image: Like this]

Comment: Note: that setting is not git specific (I am using a mixture of perforce + svn). In my case slowness went away after disabling 'Show Unversioned Files'. I had not noticed about 300,000 (!) unversioned files (build output) making the VCS commit window cripplingly slow.

Answer (score 1):

I have the some problem , to fix it open 32bit version, not 64.

Comment: 32bit Version of what?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Rename these files.

```
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PhpStorm 2020.3.2\bin\runnerw64.exe -> runnerw64--.exe
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PhpStorm 2020.3.2\bin\runnerw.exe -> runnerw--.exe
```

working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Cleaning up garbage in `git` helped me:

`git gc --prune=now --aggressive`

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on a windows 10 pc. My solution was changing line endings see below.

Refreshing a repository after changing line endings

After you've set the core.autocrlf option and committed a .gitattributes file, you may find that Git wants to commit files that you have not modified. At this point, Git is eager to change the line endings of every file for you.

The best way to automatically configure your repository's line endings is to first backup your files with Git, delete every file in your repository (except the .git directory), and then restore the files all at once.

Save your current files in Git, so that none of your work is lost.

git add . -u
git commit -m "Saving files before refreshing line endings"
Remove the index and force Git to rescan the working directory.

rm .git/index
Rewrite the Git index to pick up all the new line endings.

git reset
Show the rewritten, normalized files.

git status
Add all your changed files back, and prepare them for a commit. This is your chance to inspect which files, if any, were unchanged.

git add -u

## It is perfectly safe to see a lot of messages here that read

## "warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in file."

Rewrite the .gitattributes file.

git add .gitattributes
Commit the changes to your repository.

git commit -m "Normalize all the line endings"

Source: https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/#refreshing-a-repository-after-changing-line-endings

Comment: Please consider bringing the content in from the link to expand your answer. The problem being that if the link dies you answer offers very little. Please see [answer] for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that in IntelliJ IDEA, using the "Directory" option (and not "Project") of "Version Control" settings and adding only the project directories used will make the VCS refresh fast and responsive.
The IDEA version 2019.3 has a bug regarding this that is fixed in [2019.3.1](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-224516)

Answer (score 0):

My be I'm late,
I Unable to login to git through Android studio, it "checking URL..." forever. I tried clearing cache and restart, nothing helped me.

**The Alternate way is..(Solution)**

Download GitHub Desktop(you can use git through CMD if you know),
First Login to GitHub Desktop.

1. go to File, select 'Add local Repository'.
2. select your Project folder, if you not initialized git in that folder
   before, it will ask you to create so do it.
3. Then commit locally, then it will ask
   'Publish' click it,
4. Now you can see your Rep on your GitHub website.
   now open android Studio it automatically set to GitHub.

You can see all git control symbols on the top right side of android Studio. Push, commit and all will work.

I bypassed login through Android studio like this.
This might helpful to you.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31501248)

Answer (score 0):

Just try to `File > Close Project` and re-open it again. Quite often it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I had a similar problem, and I managed to solve it by keeping the local structure as close to the structure in the VCS as possible.
This happened using SVN.
After a clean checkout things worked well. I synced my old structure, which also served as my test deploy folder (thus a lot of non-code, non-commit files and folders have accumulated there over the months), over to the clean version: Now the clean version was unusable again.
This I was expecting, and so started to trim all that was unwanted to create a lean and clean development structure without bloat, syncing code changes to a separate deploy directory.
But my strategy did not seem to work: After a very long "updating...", IntelliJ showed only a couple of non-tracked files, but about 12k locally deleted files (I also deleted some local libs that are in the VCS, but did not remove them remotely).
I finally just synced with the VCS again, and voila, almost instantly everything was back to normal and file changes are updated almost immediately now.

Answer (score 0):

I've also run into this issue. So, I solved it by upgrading intellij idea on a mac by running:

```
brew upgrade intellij-idea
```

Answer (score -1):

When I use Git, IDEA VCS works well. But when I use **Subversion**, this question still exists and file status refresh slowly in IDEA. I have tried many top ranking methods, but they doesn't solve my problem. I remembered I update TortoiseSVN to version 1.13.1 recently. Finally, I **downgraded TortoiseSVN's version** to **1.10.5**, problem solved.[TortoiseSVN provides v1.13.1 and v1.10.5 on download page.](https://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html). Someone can  try this method if top ranking methods are useless for you.

Answer (score -2):

I think the fast way it that: you can check the code to a new directory!